# this circular queue never gives me the queue is full, why?

Tags: c

the program never gives me queue is full, why? whenever it compiles it keeps adding items to the queue even if it's full it gets overridden.
despite being everything logic to me but whenever i compile never gives queue is full when reaching to tail=4 and head =0 which is 1 of the two conditions of the isfull() functions so why does the queue reset itself instead of giving me that it is full!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_QUEUE_SIZE 5

int head = -1, tail = -1;

void enqueue(int*, int*, int);
int dequeue(int*, int*);
int queue_is_empty(int*, int*);
int queue_is_full(void);
void display(void);

int queue[MAX_QUEUE_SIZE];

void main(void)
{
    dequeue(&tail, &head);
    enqueue(&tail, &head, 1);
    enqueue(&tail, &head, 2);
    enqueue(&tail, &head, 3);
    enqueue(&tail, &head, 4);
    display();
    enqueue(&tail, &head, 5);
    display();
    enqueue(&tail, &head, 6);
    display();
    enqueue(&tail, &head, 7);
    enqueue(&tail, &head, 8);
    display();
}

void enqueue(int* tailptr, int* headptr, int data)
{
    if (!(queue_is_full()))
    {
        if (*headptr == -1)
        {
            *headptr = 0;
        }
        (*tailptr) = (*tailptr + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE;
        queue[*tailptr] = data;
        printf("\nYou've inserted->\t%d", data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The queue is full\n");
    }
}

int dequeue(int* tailptr, int* headptr)
{
    if (!queue_is_empty(tailptr, headptr))
    {
        int data;
        data = queue[*headptr];
        if (*tailptr == *headptr)
        {
            *tailptr = -1;
            *headptr = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            (*headptr) = (*headptr + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE;
        }
        printf("\nYou've deleted->\t%d", data);
        return(data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The queue is empty\n");
    }
}

int queue_is_full(void)
{
    if ((tail + 1 == head) || (((head = 0) && (tail == MAX_QUEUE_SIZE - 1))))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int queue_is_empty(int* tailptr, int* headptr)
{
    return ((*headptr) == -1) ? 1 : 0;
}

void display(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nHead->%d", head);
    printf("\tItems-> ");
    for (i = head; i != tail; i = (i + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE)
    {
        printf("%d\t", queue[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\t", queue[i]);
    printf("\tTail->%d", tail);
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: The function `queue_is_full` takes no account that the queue is circular. More generally, how do you distinguish a full circular buffer from empty, without also having a count of the number of items buffered?

Comment: Oh, I see how you avoided a modulus, and a count (you don't use the full capacity) - but there is a bug: `(head = 0)` should be `(head == 0)`.

Comment: I also get the compiler warning C4715: *'dequeue': not all control paths return a value.*

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in your queue_is_full function. The following is the right version.

```
int queue_is_full(void)
{
    if (((tail + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE == head) || (((head == 0) && (tail == MAX_QUEUE_SIZE - 1))))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Issues are the `(tail + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE == head` and `head == 0` ( you gave only one `=`)

Comment: The modulus is not needed, the second part deals with that although OP's solution is clumsy.

Comment: Yap, you are right. However, the bug `head=0` was the main issue